# IF statement for different lines

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, command-line

Question is simple, but I can't find a fast and elegant way to solve.

I want to decide next: if block size of files is more than 6 then I should print filenames.

```
stat a.txt b.txt | awk '/Blocks/ {print $4} /File/ {print $2}'
```

This code returns

```
'a.txt'
3
'b.txt'
10
```

But if I use `NR==...` it cuts row with filename.

Comment: I've added an answer, but what would be very helpful to clarify is what your desired output from this would be. It's not at all clear.

Comment: [edit] your question to include sample output from your stat command plus the expected output from your awk command given that as input so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the output of `stat` to make processing easier (requiring GNU `stat`):

```
stat -c '%b %n' a.txt b.txt | awk '$1 > 6 {print $2}'
```

where (excerpts from [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html))

> `%b` number of blocks allocated
>   `%n` file name

Or, if your filenames contain special characters, you can get them to be printed with quotes:

```
stat -c '%b %N'
```

where

> `%N` quoted file name with dereference if symbolic link

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
stat a.txt b.txt | awk '/File/{filename=$2} $1~/Size/ && $4>6 {print filename, $2}`
```

Where we capture the file name to variable `filename` and then later if we find the `Size` row and the second column is greater than 6, we print the file name and the block size.

I'm kind of guessing here what you are after though.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing `stat` nice output and using `awk` for that does not seem like the best solution for me to this. `stat` has output printf modifier, which you can just print the information you need.

Here I use find with xargs with some shell comparision:

```
find a.txt b.txt -printf "%b\0%f\0" | xargs -0 -n2 -- sh -c '[ "$1" -gt 6 ] && echo "$2"' --
```

or if you need stat:

```
stat a.txt b.txt --printf="%b\0%n\0" | xargs -0 -n2 -- sh -c '[ "$1" -gt 6 ] && echo "$2"' --
```

But if you don't need to handle all characters in filenames, maybe this will suffice:

```
stat a.txt b.txt --printf="%b %n\n" | awk '{$1>6}1' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

or more awk less cut:

```
stat a.txt b.txt --printf="%b %n\n" | awk '{if ($1>6) { print $2; }}'
```